# javascript sleep with SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout

I'm trying to send emails with a 10 seconds delay between. I wrote this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        setTimeout("SendEmail(" + i + ")", 5000);
    }
});

function SendEmail(id) {
    $.get("mimesender.php?id=" + id, function(data) {
        var toAppend = "<span>     " + data + "</span>"
        $("#sentTo").append(toAppend);
    });
}
```

server side code(php)  gets the id and selects the email with the specified id from the database

```
$query="select email from clienti where id =".$id;
```

then sends the email, and sends back the current email

```
echo email;
```

However, something is wrong here. It seems like the the js function waits for 5 seconds, and then displays all the 20 email addresses at once.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ? any "sleep "workaround will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: simply because your for loop doesn't wait the 5 seconds.

Comment: All the `setTimeout`s are basically called at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a function which calls itself after 5 seconds

```
var i=0;

function sendEmailNow() {
     SendEmail(i);
     ++i;
   if(i<20) {
        setTimeout(sendEmailNow, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: @PointedEars Yes, it can be done. And I also agree global variables are evil but that is concern in JavaScript applications or webpage using much of JS code. Here I am not passing function construct (to avoid global variable) only for making it more readable (which is also desired).

Comment: This can be done without global  `i` and without a function expression, see other answers. But function expressions are an important tool one should learn about.

Answer (score 3):

Use interval instead of loop.

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/xfVa9/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tmr;
    var i=0;
    tmr=setInterval(function(){
        if(i<20){
            SendEmail(i);
            alert("Sent "+i)
            i++;
        }else{
            clearInterval(tmr);
        }

    },5000)

 });
```

Comment: +1 for using `setInterval`. Be aware, though, that `i` is being declared as a global variable. Here's an improved example: http://jsfiddle.net/xfVa9/3/

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that you call setTimeout 20 times, just after one another, with a timeout of 5 seconds. So naturally, all emails gets sent at once. You could change the loop to look like this:

```
for (i=0;i<20;i++) {
    setTimeout("SendEmail("+ i + ")",(i+1)*5000);
}
```

There's alot of other options though, and they'd depend on just what suits your specific problem best.

Answer (score 2):

First, pass a function to `setTimeout`.

Secondly, you'd be better off if you set the timeout for the next one in the queue after the current one is finished.

In the `for` loop:

```
sendEmail(0); // start sending first
```

and in the callback:

```
      , function(data) {
          if(id < 19) { // if next should be sent
              setTimeout(function() {
                  SendEmail(id + 1);
              }, 5000);
          }
          var toAppend = "<span>     " + data + "</span>"
          $("#sentTo").append(toAppend);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is setting up 20 timers to wait 5 seconds, then letting them all go at once.

Try something like this:

```
var email_count = 20;

var sendMails = function(){
    SendEmail(email_count--);
    if(email_count > 0){
        setTimeout(sendMails, 5000);
    }
}

setTimeout(sendMails, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid jQuery. Learn JavaScript.
2. `var i = 0;` (otherwise leak into outer scope or runtime error)
3. Extra closure:

   ```
   window.setTimeout(
     (function (j) {
        return function () {
          sendEmail(j);
        };
      }(i)),
     i * 10000);
   ```
4. `sendEmail` (code style: not a constructor)
5. You really want to escape `$id` in the server-side code to prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#SQL_injection).