# JavaScript sleep/wait before continuing

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, sleep, wait

I have a JavaScript code that I need to add a sleep/wait function to. The code I am running is already in a function, eg:

```
function myFunction(time)
{
    alert('time starts now');
    //code to make the program wait before continuing
    alert('time is up')
}
```

I have heard that a possible solution might include

```
setTimeout
```

but I am not sure how to use it in this case.

I can't use PHP, as my server does not support it, although using jQuery would be fine.

Comment: The code would be `setTimeout(function(){ alert('time is up')},time);` (instead of the `\\` line and the `alert` line below it), time is given in miliseconds https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: For which reason would you have to make your script wait?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Would it be possible to make a function sleepNow(time), that you can call within the script, such as sleepNow(5000) to sleep 5 seconds?

Comment: function sleep( _ms = 0 )
 {
  var _start = new Date().getTime();
  while( _ms > ( new Date().getTime() - _start ) ){}
 }

Comment: I would like to reopen this questions. Becauae here we can give answers that relevant only to browsers,

Answer (score 690, accepted):

JS does not have a sleep function, it has [**setTimeout()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) or [**setInterval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) functions.

If you can move the code that you need to run after the pause into the `setTimeout()` callback, you can do something like this:

```
//code before the pause
setTimeout(function(){
    //do what you need here
}, 2000);
```

see example here : http://jsfiddle.net/9LZQp/

This won't halt the execution of your script, but due to the fact that `setTimeout()` is an asynchronous function, this code

```
console.log("HELLO");
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("THIS IS");
}, 2000);
console.log("DOG");
```

will print this in the console:

```
HELLO
DOG
THIS IS
```

(note that **DOG** is printed before **THIS IS**)

---

You can use the following code to simulate a sleep for short periods of time:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

now, if you want to sleep for 1 second, just use:

```
sleep(1000);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/HrJku/1/

please note that **this code will keep your script busy for *n milliseconds*. This will not only stop execution of Javascript on your page, but depending on the browser implementation, may possibly make the page completely unresponsive, and possibly make the entire browser unresponsive**. In other words this is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: It freezes browser, and if you do `sleep` more than 10 seconds, browser shows alert: `A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.`.

Comment: JS is single threaded.. use short periods of time or find another way involving setTimeout function.

have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624427/javascript-sleep-with-settimeout

Comment: Hello!  This is a busy wait loop.  Surely it cannot be the accepted answer.

Comment: I needed a blocking sleep to test if an error was due to a time consuming task or doing an async call returning the flow of the application.  Ultimately my program will not include this function but it will help me debug.

Comment: this locks the browser, is cpu intensive, causes execution interruption on mobile devices if paused time is too long

Comment: `setTimeout()` involves callbacks, which means it is asynchronous. The OP asked for something that halts, which is synchronous and will cause interruption.

Comment: @BeNdErR, its better to use infinite loop with `while(true)` instead of `for(..)`. So that your page will respond even with big delays.

Comment: @IvanZh can you explain why `while` will respond better than `for` on big delays?

Comment: @BeNdErR, using infinite loop you will never reach the last 'i' value.
I tested `for` loop with `< 1e7` and it takes less then 20 sec in Chrome. So, I think, its better to use infinite loop or `< Number.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: -1 Horrible that this starts with a sleep function that is a busy loop. Scary that 30 people have +1'd this. I hope future readers read on to the setTimeout example that was added a year later.

Comment: I was looking for a busy loop for debugging purposes so even if this is not meant to be used in a production environment it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It is totally a valid answer to accept because it answers the question.  I found it in the context of browser automation, where pausing the entire UI for 1 second is totally fine.  It is also important to highlight the answer to ensure that people understand what the actual question is and the consequence of this answer, which has been done.

Comment: It would be a good idea to call the method "blockingSleep", to avoid tempting people to use it in the wrong context. A bit like react.js' dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

Comment: I will also say that not all JS is client-side and there *are* some definite cases in which, when reaching out to external API's, a wait is required. I'm working on one right now in which a query is POSTed to an API, then the API returns a URL, but the actual data generated in the report at the URL could take up to three seconds. So, when they want that report, I'm using the busy loop. GG answering the actual _question_ @BeNdErR

Comment: @Samuel Tulach, editing posts to include your own software library would be considered spamming read [how not to be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) to prevent this in the future.

Comment: ```function wait(ms) {
  const start = performance.now();
  while(performance.now() - start < ms);
}```