# How to create javascript delay function

Tags: javascript, function, delay, sleep, wait

I have a javascript file, and in several places I want to add a small delay, so the script would reach that point, wait 3 seconds, and then continue with the rest of the code. The best way that I thought of doing this was to create a function, which I could call from anywhere in the script.

```
function startDelay(lengthOfDelay)
{
//code to make it delay for lengthOfDelay amount of time
}
```

However, I can not find any way to implement the code to make it wait. I had a look at setTimeout, but you needed to hard code the function into it, which made it no good for me.

Is there any way that I can get the script to juct pause for a few seconds? I have no problem with the UI freezing whilst the code is paused.

If not, is there a way that I could use the PHP **sleep()** to achieve this? (I know that PHP is server side and Javascript is client side, but maybe there is a way that I have not heard of.)

Comment: The simplest way is to use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) and to do the remaining of your code in the function you give to setTimeout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312963/javascript-settimeout

Comment: just create a promise that return a settimeout, and use it in a async function to use the await: const delay =async(seconds)=>new Promise( resolve=>setTimeout(resolve,seconds));
///////

Answer (score 68):

You do not need to use an anonymous function with `setTimeout`. You can do something like this:

```
setTimeout(doSomething, 3000);

function doSomething() {
   //do whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: How would I create a function such as startDelay(lengthOfDelay) that I could call from **anywhere** in the script and have it do the rest of the code afterwards, not just _//do whatever you want here_?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to do exactly. Do you want to halt the execution of the page or schedule a function that will execute after a delay?

Comment: @Kassem I think (s)he means e.g. what if you want to console.log a message every second using a for loop? i.e. `while(true){ [a delay function, incorporating console.log]}`  I don't think your function will run sequentially.

Comment: Didn't work for me the first time, but the following solved my problem: setTimeout(function() { doSomething(); }, 3000);

Answer (score 5):

Ah yes. Welcome to Asynchronous execution.

Basically, pausing a script would cause the browser and page to become unresponsive for 3 seconds. This is horrible for web apps, and so isn't supported.

Instead, you have to think "event-based". Use setTimeout to call a function after a certain amount of time, which will continue to run the JavaScript on the page during that time.

Comment: Is there any way to do this? Making the page unresponsive is actually a positive thing for me!

Comment: fortunatelly yes: sleep.js http://stackoverflow.com/a/16873849/667927

Answer (score -1):

You can create a delay using the following example

```
setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
```

Replace **3000** with # of **milliseconds**

You can place the content of what you want executed inside the function.

Comment: This answer is slightly lacking (I think) because setInterval will continue to run every 3 seconds, not just once.

Comment: @AdamDavis I've tested this method and I haven't experienced any problems.  Should you or someone else test this and demonstrate otherwise let the community know.  Thanks

Comment: @CBC_NS I just tried it out and I also had it repeating every 3 seconds. Handy to keep in mind though.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The original post states, "I want to add a small delay, so the script would reach that point, wait 3 seconds, and then continue with the rest of the code."  This code will continually call the declared function every n milliseconds until a clearInterval is set. This could have very bad unintended consequences.

Comment: just replace setInterval with setTimeout and it works as intended