# Delay scroll down

Tags: scroll, settimeout, delay

How to delay the scroll down for few seconds?

**My Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#tmp_image-37113").click (function() {
      $('#section--41340').show(150);
      $('html, body').animate ({
        scrollTop: $("#section--41340").offset().top
      }, 2000);

      return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: deplicate to this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873889/how-to-create-javascript-delay-function

Comment: I want to delay the scroll down using the setTimeout, but I'm struggling how to place or where to put  it in into my code.