# listen to firefox load event after Node.js spawn call

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox

I need to open multiple windows/tabs of firefox using Node. Now, when i use a spawn() call:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
ff = spawn('firefox', ['www.stackoverflow.com', '-new-tab']);
```

If i use two (or more) calls right after the other, firefox claims there's a page that is not responding, and will not open another window. 
That can be solved using some implementation of [sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873323/javascript-sleep-wait-before-continuing) - which is bad practice because there's no way of knowing the actual loading time. 
This is why i'm looking for an event that is fired when a firefox window/tab is considered "not busy"-
I have searched in the ChildProcess class [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) and didn't see any event of such.
Since the page i'm loading connects to a Node http server, and uses socket.io, i was thinking of a workaround: when the page finishes loading, i'll use socket.io to notify the server that the window is ready, and then be able to open a new window- but that just seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually went with the socket.io workaround; In the client side I used jQuery in order to know when the page was fully loaded and then sent a "page loaded" message via socket.io:

```
//client side:
jQuery(function($)
{
    socket = io.connect();
    socket.emit('page loaded', {'someKey': 8);
}
```

If someone have a better way, i'de be glad to hear