# unload play delay for html 5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm not sure if it's the structure of my code or there's something I'm missing in my code, however it's seems I am have a slightly slow loading with my html video in Safari. The video plays for at least 1sec before it's actually visible... is the a way I can create a delay before the video starts playing? [click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/protein/)

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay volume="3" id="video-wall__content">
    <source src="video/ad.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video/ad.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

I have added...

`$(window).load(function () {
    $(document.body).fadeIn(2000);
    ('#video-wall-wrapper').get(0).play();
 });`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(document.body).fadeIn(2000, function(){
        ('#video-wall-wrapper').get(0).play();
    });   
});
```

The video will start only when `fadeIn` is complete. As per specs, [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) accepts 2 arguments.

- duration: A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
- complete: A function to call once the animation is complete.

This is holds true for every async event in jQuery. You always have a way to provide callback functions.

---

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay volume="3" id="video-wall__content">
```

> autoplay: Instructs the UA to automatically begin playback of the
>   video as soon as it can do so without stopping.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/video.html).

So yeah, that basically defies the whole sense of starting the video with jQuery.

Comment: then add a timer, also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873323/javascript-sleep-wait-before-continuing

Comment: btw, I'm trying it in Safari and while the first time it doesn't work if you refresh the page it works fine. Just pointing out as it might help in troubleshooting.

Comment: besides, isn't the "autoplay" tag what makes the video starts automatically? What's the sense into starting the video with jQ if you autoplay it? See updated answer!