# Date in Javascript Div loop not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to generate  3 divs in a for loop and insert the datetime in each iteration . The problem I'm running into is while the function generates the three div's  correctly it appends the same time to all 3 div's leaving me (JavaScript newbie) to believe the Date() function is only being executed once . If any we could explain to me what is going on I would greatly appreciate it. Ideally I would like to replace the Date function with graph's and have a graph load in each div.

```
function gengraphs () {
  for (i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
    var divTag = document.createElement("div");
    divTag.style.width ="1000px";
    divTag.style.height ="600px";
    divTag.id = "graph"+i;
    document.body.appendChild(divTag);
    divTag.innerHTML = Date();

    // divTag.appendChild(getGraph(divTag));   
    // divTag.innerHTML = getGraph(divTag);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The server is executing the script fast enough (in milliseconds) that the date() returned is not visibly different.  Try something to delay or use the increment variable `i`

Comment: Also when I uncomment a function that displays a graph in the place of calling Date() it only displays one graph instead of displaying three separate graphs each in its own div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7fugntds/
Try creating a jsfiddle and work out what is wrong on it.  I didn't get any `<div>` tags when I ran your code?

Comment: Remove the following two lines and it runs

Comment: divTag.style.width ="1000px";
    divTag.style.height ="600px";

Answer (score 0):

The loop is being executed so quickly that you won't see a difference in time. Try calling the contents of your loop with a significant delay (e.g. 1s) and put it into a function as shown here: [JavaScript sleep/wait before continuing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873323/javascript-sleep-wait-before-continuing)

Comment: Also when I uncomment a function that displays a graph in the place of calling Date()  it only  displays one graph instead of displaying three separate graphs each in its own div.