# Angular 2 rounterLink add handler

Tags: angular, routes, handler, routerlink

I have `routerLink` used in my template like this:

```
<li><a [routerLink]="[ 'discounts' ]">Wczesna oplata</a></li>
```

Is it possible to add a handler that would intercept that event and perform some action - like logging click - before routing takes place ?

Answer (score 3):

Just add a click property:

```
<li ><a [routerLink]="[ 'discounts' ]" (click)="clicked()">Wczesna oplata</a></li>
```

Then in the component:

```
export class AppCom {
    clicked() {
        console.log('clicked');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, what @John mentioned should work, but I would suggest you a generic solution for your problem. By adding directive component, you don't have to add you logging method everywhere:

```
import {Directive, Renderer, ElementRef, HostListener} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: '[routerLink]'
})

export class FooClickTracker {

    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
        renderer.listen(elementRef.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
            console.log('clicked', event, elementRef.nativeElement);
        });
    }
}
```

You can verify that the listener will execute before routing takes place:

```
constructor(elementRef:ElementRef, renderer:Renderer) {
    renderer.listen(elementRef.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
        console.log('clicked', event, elementRef.nativeElement);
        this.sleep(5000)
    });
}

// we can mock waiting for small period of time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873323/javascript-sleep-wait-before-continuing
private sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```