# How to solve parquetjs library problem - error with async?

Tags: node.js, parquet

I tried using parquetjs:
`https://www.npmjs.com/package/parquetjs`

Code from their example:

```
var parquet = require('parquetjs');

// declare a schema for the `fruits` table
var schema = new parquet.ParquetSchema({
  name: { type: 'UTF8' },
  quantity: { type: 'INT64' },
  price: { type: 'DOUBLE' },
  date: { type: 'TIMESTAMP_MILLIS' },
  in_stock: { type: 'BOOLEAN' }
});

// create new ParquetWriter that writes to 'fruits.parquet'
var writer = await parquet.ParquetWriter.openFile(schema, 'fruits.parquet');

// append a few rows to the file
await writer.appendRow({name: 'apples', quantity: 10, price: 2.5, date: new Date(), in_stock: true});
await writer.appendRow({name: 'oranges', quantity: 10, price: 2.5, date: new Date(), in_stock: true});
```

Error:
`SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

What should be the problem (since they posted this as example)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [await is only valid in async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432579/await-is-only-valid-in-async-function)

Comment: I copy pasted from their example. Why need this change? Is their example wrong?

Comment: the free scope isn't an async context.

Comment: What is 'free' scope?

Answer (score 0):

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

What that means is you can `await` keyword in only a function which has `async` keyword in the function signature.

As a quick work around, you can use a `async` IIFE.

```
(async() => {
    // create new ParquetWriter that writes to 'fruits.parquet'
    var writer = await parquet.ParquetWriter.openFile(schema, 'fruits.parquet');

    // append a few rows to the file
    await writer.appendRow({name: 'apples', quantity: 10, price: 2.5, date: new Date(), in_stock: true});
    await writer.appendRow({name: 'oranges', quantity: 10, price: 2.5, date: new Date(), in_stock: true});
})()
```