# How to resolve the Syntax error : await is only valid in async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have written a code to return some data from asynchronous call using promise. While I try to execute I get "Syntax Error await is only valid in async function" and also I get Cannot proxy application requests...Error: connect ECONNREFUSED.

I'm unsure why I get these errors

I have tried using async before the function calls, but it didn't work

```
var http = require('https');
var httpGet = function(url) {
  return new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {
    http.get(url,function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      var body = ''; 
      res.on('data', function(chunk){ 
        body += chunk;
        console.log("The body is "+ body);
      });
      res.on('end',function(){resolve(body);});
    }).on('error', reject);
  });
};

var body = await httpGet('link');
$.response.setBody(body);
```

I would want variable body to have the data returned from the httpGet function. Right now I'm getting the above mentioned errors. But without using await, I get the value of body as '{}'.

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [await is only valid in async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432579/await-is-only-valid-in-async-function)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) can only be called in a function marked as [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). 
so, you can make an `async IIFE` and call the `httpGet` from there.

```
(async function(){
    var body = await httpGet('link');
    $.response.setBody(body);
})()
```

Basically when you use one `asynchronous` operation, you need to make the entire flow asynchronous as well. So the `async` keyword kindof uses ES6 generator function and makes it return a promise.

You can check [this](https://javascript.info/async-await) out if you have confusion.

Comment: Thanks it works. But I'm not able to store the data in a global variable. Below is what i tried. var result;
   (async function(){
    result = await httpGet('link');
    $.response.setBody(result);
})()
   console.log("The result is "+result);

Comment: I get the result as undefined. How to retrieve the data and store in a global variable? Here i'm not able to set the body too. It returns null value

Comment: You will get the result undefined because the `console.log` will run just after initating the `async` function. You cannot use sync and async operations at the same time.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to solve this issue? I'm stuck with this

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the data. If you want to show it in ui then make a placeholder page, and after the data is there change the page. Or if you want to use a route to return it as an api response you can do that also.

Comment: I would like to store the data in some global variable and use that for other operations in the same file. Is it possible?

Comment: ha obviously but you need to do the other operations AFTER the httpGet operation. That means you can do any operations after the `await` in the `async` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195285/discussion-between-arun-elangovan-and-aritra-chakraborty).

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

I initially had:

```
exports.doSomething = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    // ... 

    const [response] = await tasksClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task });
});
```

But I added the word `async` here  (before the **open parentheses** to **snapshot**) and then the error went away

```
       // here
.onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
```

So now the code is

```
exports.doSomething = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postId}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

    // ... 

    const [response] = await tasksClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task });
});
```