# Why is a function async when it calls another async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I thought I understood how to use async and await till I saw the below code snippet.

So there is an onInput event handler function attached to the movie input textbox. Within it is called the **fetchData** asynchronous function which uses the await keyword to wait for results from the axios.get function.

My question is, why do we need to make the onInput function also async? I mean, the fetchData function is async. Which means, it will wait till the axios.get is resolved and the execution will be paused till axios.get is resolved. So when the line const movies = fetchData(event.target.value); executes, the fetchData function will be executed which will pause on the await axios.get statement. So why do we need to use await while calling fetchData and make onInput async??

```
const fetchData = async(searchTerm)=>{
    const results =  await axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/', {
    params:{
        apikey:'d9835cc5',
        s: searchTerm
        }

    });
    return results.data.Search;
}

    const movieInput = document.querySelector('input');
    
    
    const onInput = async event => {
        const movies = await fetchData(event.target.value);
        console.log(movies);
    }
    
    movieInput.addEventListener('input', onInput);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean, the fetchData function is async. Which means, it will wait till the axios.get is resolved and the execution will be paused till axios.get is resolved.

This concept is hiding a lot of detail that may be confusing, such as that paused execution is resumed using callback functions.

- `async` functions do not pause execution of their callers.

  Instead they return a promise that will be resolved with the value syntactically returned from executing the `async` function body. To be clear, the value apparently returned from within an `async` function body is **not** returned to the caller directly - the caller gets a promise for it.
- When executed the `await` **operator** sets up  call backs for when its operand promise becomes settled. Effectively it calls the `then` method of its promise operand to supply a set of `onfulfilled` and `onrejected` callbacks, before storing the current execution context in memory and returning to the event loop.

  When it receives a callback from promise settlement, the `await` operator restores the execution context it previously saved. If the awaited promise is rejected, `await` throws the rejection reason. If fulfilled, `await` resumes exection and returns the fulfilled value of the promise as the result of executing the `await` operator.

Now historically `await` was never a reserved keyword - not mentioned in ES3, future reserved keyword in ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) but reserved word in the current draft of ECMAscript as at May 2021.

Hence, to retain compatibility with code on the web, `await` was only recognized as an operator if it occurs within an `async` function - leaving it available as an identifier outside of `async` function bodies.

Likewise the `async` keyword was not historically reserved, but was able to be introduced without comparability issues by requiring its usage in a position that would have produced an unexpected identifier error in previous versions of JavaScript. Meaning before the `function` keyword or before an arrow function expression.

Finally you need to declare `onInput` as an `async` function because `await` is being used as an operator within its body. Without the `async` declaraton, `await` will be treated as an identifier rather than the name of an operator.

As a side note, the promise returned by `onInput` is being discarded and could generate an uncaught promise rejection error in its current form.

---

To answer the slightly different question of "why does `await` need to be used in the `onInput` function at all?", the value returned from `fetchData` is a pending promise. In order to set `movies` to the `results.data.Search` value obtained within `fetchData`, you need to wait for the fulfilled value of the returned promise. Using `async/await` is one means of doing so. The other is to add a fulfillment handler to the promise returned from `fetchData` by calling its `then` method.

Comment: I think the `async` token was never thought of as a compatibility solution. Even if it wasn't necessary, [it's still a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31485350/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi I've made parts of the answer  more direct.  Checking in Firefox showed that  `async` and `await` can still be used as identifiers outside of an `async` function to this day. Certainly agree that using `async` before an asynchronous function declaration is a good idea, not to mention it creates an `AsyncFuntion` object instead of a `Function` object!

Comment: @traktor would execution of the oninput function be paused on the line "const movies = await fetchData(event.target.value);"? I am understanding that it should pause and wait for the promise to resolve. Is that correct?

Comment: @theju112t  JavaScript is single threaded - when called from the event loop task manager, script code continues until it returns to the task manager. The `await` operator in `onInput` stores the current execution environment and returns to the event loop, enabling other event driven JavaScript to be called and run from the event loop. Evaluation of the `await` operator expression within `onInput` resumes when one of the handlers added to the `fetchData()...)` promise is called. Call it "paused" if you like, but thinking of it as "suspended until something happens" may be clearer.

Comment: Seems like the async await implementation duplicates an entire set of function/methods which are nearly identical. I wonder if the same synch and async function can serve both roles. Perhaps, using special scoping  or by leveraging the existing generics infrastructure.

Comment: @ATL_DEV Synchronous functions are constructed by `Function` and async functions by `AsyncFunction`. The latter extends `Function` as a class, inheriting methods and properties of  `Function` that it doesn't replace. The constructors have to be different - `Function` doesn't know about async functions (they're just a promise returning function) or what to do with `await` as an operator, but will return values as coded. `AsyncFunction` instances handle the  `async` operator and return a pending promise (before any awaited results are known).  Special scoping, leveraging: `Class extends`.

Comment: @traktor The entire asynchronous programming feature  in C++ a horrible hack job. Async/await keywords are build into C#, but they depend on external runtime code to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `await` operator inside `inInput`. It's a JavaScript rule that functions using `await` must be async, so `inInput` must also be async. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56685416/13357440

Also, MDN has useful information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Ya I understand that part.. await can be used only inside an async function. My question is, why do we need to make onInput async at all? Isnt it enough that fetchData is async and it awaits on a particular line?

Comment: @theju112t - you don't, it could easily be written: `const onInput = event => fetchOptions(event.target.value)` and the end result would be the exact same, a promise is returned. Some people like the annotation of `async` so you can tell **at a glance** that a function returns a promise, but it's personal preference at that point.

Comment: @theju112t If you didn't need the result of that call to `fetchData`, you could make `onInput` not async and omit the `await`, but you want the return value from `fetchData` so you need to use `await`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953976/does-an-async-function-always-need-to-be-called-with-await

Comment: @atultw - `but you want the return value from fetchData so you need to use await` - this is wrong. `onInput` returns the exact same promise regardless of using `await` or not.

Comment: @Adam ya but I dont want the promise as the return value. I want the actual data after the promise is resolved.

Comment: @theju112t - think about that for a second...both ways the function returns the same promise that you have to `await` or call `.then` on to get at the data. The return value will be the same no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would want API calls to execute while the rest of your program runs, so the `onInput` would be async. Furthermore, javascript mandates that an await is inside of an async function, so the code was simply following its standards and rules as well. Typically, once the top level is an async, everything inside of it is just following the structure. More info can be found [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-async-await-in-javascript-1d81bb079b2c).