# Nods.js router throws "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await

I have a Nodejs structure that separates the router and the controller.

And I try to use Async-Await inside the controller but I get `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`.

Is my syntax wrong?

Why do I get `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` for Await?

**routes**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const authController = require('../controller/auth_controller');

router.post('/login', authController.login);

module.exports = router;
```

**controller**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const User = require('../model/index');

const { jwtSign } = require('../mixin/jwt');

exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const secretKey = req.app.get('jwt-secret');

  let sql = `SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?`;

  try {
    User.query(sql, [email], (err, result) => {
      ...
      else {
        const token = await jwtSign(secretKey, result[0].userId, email);
      ...
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

**mixin/jwtSign**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

exports.jwtSign = async (secretKey, userId, email) => {
  const token = jwt.sign(
    {
      userId: userId,
      email: email
    },
    secretKey
  );

  return token;
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [await is only valid in async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432579/await-is-only-valid-in-async-function)

Comment: Your `(err, result) => {` is not `async`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace:

```js
User.query(sql, [email], (err, result) => {
```

With:

```js
User.query(sql, [email], async (err, result) => {
```

To make it an `async` function.