# How do I achieve my requirement of synchronus execution in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I've a requirement where I have to call another function for a record of data before I actually perform next set of operations.

so here's what I'm doing but it doesn't work. function a is stored in a common library abc

```
var a = (req,callBack) =>{
DB Operation
.
.
.
.
callBack(null,result);
}

var b = (req,callBack) =>{
const c = await abc.a(req,response);
DB Operation
.
.
.
.
.
callBack(null,result);
}
```

when I do const c = await abc.a(req,response); it gives me error "await is only valid in async function" but I've seen examples where await is used like this.

can you please help me with this.

Comment: I think the error message is somewhat self-explanatory... is it not? [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49432579/1541563)

Comment: _"but I've seen examples where await is used like this"_ - Then you've missed the `async` in the examples

Answer (score 1):

You are not using async/await properly. Await only works inside async functions. So make your function async.

```
var b = async (req,callBack) =>{ // made this function async
    abc.a(req, (_, res) => {
        DB Operation
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        callBack(null,result);
    });
}
```

Comment: That dint help it gives a warning 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression. and when I test it it doesnt wait for response.

Comment: If function a which is a library function returns a callback. Then you don't need to use async/await. You can just have your data in callback response.

Answer (score 0):

You'r code would like.

```
async function a () {
  const b = await funcX()
}
```

or

```
const b =  async () => {
  const b = await funcX()
}
```

like that

Answer (score 0):

`await` is only valid if the called function returns a `promise`, or is marked `async`.

Furthermore, `await` must be used from within an `async` function.

Both are false in your case.

Don't use async/await...

```
var b = (req,callBack) =>{
 abc.a(req,c=>{
  DB Operation
  callBack(null,result);
 });
}
```

You can wrap your functions inside `async` functions if you insist on using that syntax.