# Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Tags: reactjs

Line 20:19:  Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

```
  18 | 
  19 |     try{
  20 |       const res = await axios.post('/upload', formData, {
     |                   ^
  21 |         headers:{
  22 |           'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
  23 |         }
```

Comment: What is the function signature? You're showing some of the code but not the entire function. The error is saying that your function isn't async

Comment: Please post the entire function. Also I think the error is pretty self-explanatory. Just add `async` in front of your function declaration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [await is only valid in async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432579/await-is-only-valid-in-async-function)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use directly await like this. You should create a function with async and then you can use await in function like that;

```
const myFunction = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('bla')
  }
}
```

Comment: const onSubmit = async => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    FormData.append("file", file);

    try {
      const res = axios.post("/upload", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      });

      const { filename, filePath } = res.data;

      setUploadedFile({ filename, filePath });
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response.status === 500) {
        console.log("there was a problem with the server");
      } else {
        console.log(err.response.data.msg);
      }
    }
  };

Comment: @Massimo555 so, what is the problem? why you doesn't add await keyword before axios function?

Comment: @Massimo555 I think the issue is the onSubmit function. Right now, your function is synchronous but has a parameter called async. By adding empty braces, you can change it to an async function which doesn't take any arguments:  `const onSubmit = async => {` becomes  `const onSubmit = async () => {`. Now you got yourself an async function that you can use `await` in.

Comment: i added await before the axios and its started throwing an error....that's what i want to debug and fix but i need help to do that

Comment: thanks everyone the code is now working....i appreciate the help....no more errors