# Code runs fine on console but gives error when injected by browser extension(works on chrome not in firefox)

Tags: javascript, browser-extension

The extension injects the following code:

```
var forbidden;
console.log("url: ",window.location.href);
async function fetchData(link) {
    return fetch(link)
    .then(response =>response.text())
    .then(text => text.split(/\r|\n/))
}
forbidden=await fetchData(`https://truemysterious98.github.io/Page/uploads/txt/url/url.txt`);
for (var i =0;i<forbidden.length;i++){
    console.log(forbidden[i]);
    if(window.location.href.includes(forbidden[i])) window.location= 'https://truemysterious98.github.io/Page/t/m.html';
}
```

gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`
but when runned on console manually it works.Await is used as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432579/await-is-only-valid-in-async-function)

[here is a video demo of the problem .](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4V8U7CLE24)

Comment: The error seems pretty clear: you cannot use `await` outside of an `async` function.

Comment: Browser consoles are somewhat weird environments, so it can be hard to use those for such testing.

Comment: will it not stop in console too? await is used as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432579/await-is-only-valid-in-async-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the code manually in the console because [Chrome DevTools support "Top-level await"](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#await).

> Top-level await enables developers to use the await keyword outside of
>   async functions. It acts like a big async function causing other
>   modules who import them to wait before they start evaluating their
>   body.

To fix your code, you can simply wrap your code with an async function and run that function. Here is a possible implementation:

```
async function fetchData(link) {
  return fetch(link)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((text) => text.split(/\r|\n/));
}

async function main() {
  console.log("url: ", window.location.href);
  var forbidden = await fetchData(
    `https://truemysterious98.github.io/Page/uploads/txt/url/url.txt`
  );
  for (var i = 0; i < forbidden.length; i++) {
    console.log(forbidden[i]);
    if (window.location.href.includes(forbidden[i]))
      window.location = "https://truemysterious98.github.io/Page/t/m.html";
  }
}

main();
```

More info about [Top-level await](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await).