# How can i fix this error : SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am trying to create a discord bot to display some informations about cryptocurrencies and there is the following error SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function, there is the part of the code that make me problems :

```
 const [coin, vsCurrency] = args;
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
        `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=${coin}&vs_currencies=${vsCurrency}`
        );
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you can't use `await` except inside a function that starts with `async ...`, so if this code isn't even in a function: put it in a function, then call that function. And if it _is_ in a function, mark it as an asynchronous function using `async`. Alternatively, don't use `await` if you don't need auto-unpacking of a promise, just use the Promise you're given: `axios.get(...).then(...).catch(...)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [await is only valid in async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432579/await-is-only-valid-in-async-function)  It's the first link doing a google search for your error, and the first link doing a search on stackoverflow.  You should always do this before posting a question to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule number one: **Read the error**.

What it tells you is that you can use the `await` keyword **only** inside an `async` function. So your piece of code must be wrapped like this:

```js
async function run() {

 const [coin, vsCurrency] = args;
 try {
   const { data } = await axios.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/priceids=${coin}&vs_currencies=${vsCurrency}`);
 } catch (err) {
   // Do something about the error.
 }
}

// Don't forget to run your function
run();
```

Read [this](https://javascript.info/async-await) for a better understanding of `async/await`.

Comment: ok thank you very much, i tried this in the following way but my discord bot is still not working i don't know what to do

Comment: @SoufBsslr make sure to accept my answer if it fits you, so your question does not appear anymore in the pending questions list.

Comment: If you have another problem @SoufBsslr ask another question!