# use async and await in nth instead of first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

The Error is showing exactly what is the problem, but what is bypass if i want to use in nTH function await ?.

To be more clear. `address_submited()` is called from html `onclick=address_submited()`

It read the wallet_address and start fetching data by `GET` request from `OpenSea`. There may be multiple calls depending on results. This function is solved by callback so 'it waits' untill it fetch all data.

Once the data is obtainted now inside a for loop it should do another API call for every single member. Since provider limited 50 calls per minute we need to add some delay. That's why i added the `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));`

Not it returns me back to start as described on this question : [await is only valid in async function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49432604/15985235)

```
async function address_submited() {
    const wallet_address = $('#wallet_id').val()
    start_app(wallet_address, 0, [])
}

function start_app(wallet_id, offset, all_events) {
    $.get('https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/events',
        {
            "account_address": wallet_id,
            "only_opensea": "false",
            "event_type": "successful",
            "offset": offset,
            "limit": "50"
        }).done(function (return_data) {
            all_events = all_events.concat(return_data['asset_events'])
            offset += return_data['asset_events'].length
            if (return_data['asset_events'].length != 0) {
                start_app(wallet_id, offset, all_events)
            } else {
                read_events(all_events)
            }
        })
}

function read_events(_all_events) {
    Object.entries(_all_events).forEach(item => {
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
        $.get(`https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=${item[1]["transaction"]["transaction_hash"]}&apikey=${etherscan_api_key}`).
            done(function (return_data) { 
                console.log(return_data)
            }) 
    })
}
```

Comment: `.forEach(async item => ...)`

Comment: @Barmar still don't have 2 seconds sleep between requests.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this.

```
function read_events(_all_events) {
Object.entries(_all_events).forEach(async (item) => {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
    $.get(`https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=${item[1]["transaction"]["transaction_hash"]}&apikey=${etherscan_api_key}`).
        done(function (return_data) { 
            console.log(return_data)
        }) 
})
}
```

Comment: @Shubdam Prajapat still don't have 2 seconds sleep between requests.