# I keep getting this error on my unban command discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfJfh.png)

module.exports = {
name: 'unban',
description: "Used to unban members from a server",
execute(message, args, Discord, client) {

```
if (!(message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.id === "783700556472254525"))) return

  let reason;

  const user = await bot.users.fetch(args[0])

  if (!args[1])
  {
    reason = "Not specified"
  }

  else
  {
    reason = args[1]
  }

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`${user.username} was unbanned!`)
  .setDescription(`${user.username} was unbanned by ${message.author.username} for: ${reason}`)
  .setColor("GREEN")
  .setFooter("Unban Command")
  .setTimestamp()

  message.channel.send(embed)

  message.guild.members.unban(user)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [await is only valid in async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432579/await-is-only-valid-in-async-function)

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because to use await, the execute function has to be asynchronous, so all you have to do is add `async` before the execute like this: `async execute() {}`. This is why, it is better to actually spend some time and learn the language instead of copy pasting since many error like this can be easily answered.

Comment: I tryed it gave me another error

Comment: What is the error?