# Trouble getting Google's Bluetooth Web API to run in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bluetooth-gatt

I'd like to read the battery level of the connected Bluetooth devices. I found this web API and almost have it running. It asks permission to access bluetooth, but then gives an error when connecting to the API I think.

Here's the Google Web Bluetooth API:
https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/battery-level.html

Here's the first error:
*Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules*

My javascript code:

```
const button = document.getElementById("getDetails");
const details = document.getElementById("details");

button.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  try {
    // Request the Bluetooth device through the browser
    const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
      optionalServices: ["battery_service", "device_information"],
      acceptAllDevices: true,
    });

    // Connect to the GATT server and get the name of the Bluetooth device
    const server = await device.gatt.connect();
    let deviceName = device.gatt.device.name;

    // Getting the services we mentioned before through GATT server
    const batteryService = await server.getPrimaryService("battery_service");
    const infoService = await server.getPrimaryService("device_information");

    // Getting the current battery level
    const batteryLevelCharacteristic = await batteryService.getCharacteristic(
      "battery_level"
    );
    // Convert received buffer to number
    const batteryLevelValue = await batteryLevelCharacteristic.readValue();
    const batteryPercent = batteryLevelValue.getUint8(0);

    // Getting device information
    // We will get all characteristics from device_information
    const infoCharacteristics = await infoService.getCharacteristics();

    // Store promises in an array for parallel execution
    const infoPromises = infoCharacteristics.map(async (characteristic) => {
      // Returns a buffer
      const value = await characteristic.readValue();
      // Convert the buffer to string
      return new TextDecoder().decode(value);
    });

    // Await all promises to resolve
    const infoValues = await Promise.all(infoPromises);

    console.log(infoValues);

    // Display all the information on the screen
    // use innerHTML
    details.innerHTML = `
      Device Name - ${deviceName}<br />
      Battery Level - ${batteryPercent}%<br />
      Device Information:
      <ul>
        ${infoValues.map((value) => `<li>${value}</li>`).join("")}
      </ul> 
    `;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    alert("An error occurred while fetching device details");
  }
});
```

I tried applying this stack overflow answer, but have been unsuccessful.

[await is only valid in async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432579/await-is-only-valid-in-async-function)