# How to wait for a function to execute in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that if a user clicks **D** a functions gets executes after one second and if a person clicks **A** before the code in timeout is executed, I want it to wait for the code to get executed. I dont know if this is possible with code I wrote. If it's possible please let me know how to do it. Any help will be highly appreciable. JQuery can be used too.

```js
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
  // D click
  if (e.key === 'd' || e.key === 'D') {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('d clicked')
    }, 1000)
  }
  // A click
  else if (e.key === 'a' || e.key === 'A') {
    console.log('a clicked')
  }
});
```

Comment: Set a global flag `dIsRunning` to true before the timeout. Set it to false within the timeout. Check if the flag is false before running anything else.

Comment: Actually I'm a bit new to javascript so I dont know much about it. Can you explain it with a code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wait until condition is met or timeout is passed in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054748/wait-until-condition-is-met-or-timeout-is-passed-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript promises to solve that problem. With them, it's possible to set a function to be executed right after another, that is, attaching callbacks, without polluting your code.

Read mode about promises here: [Promise - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

In the code below, when 'a' is pressed, it verifies if there is a promise for 'd'. If so, it waits for the promise to be fulfilled, printing 'a clicked' to the console afterwards. If no, it prints the message at the same moment.

```js
let d;

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    // D click
    if (e.key === 'd' || e.key === 'D') {
        d = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('d clicked');
                resolve();
            }, 1000)
        });
    }
    // A click
    else if (e.key === 'a' || e.key === 'A') {
        if (d) {
            d.then(() => {
                console.log('a clicked');
                d = null;
            })
        } else {
            console.log('a clicked');
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No need for the global `d`, which actually causes some issues.  For example, rapidly press the D key a bunch of times.  Note that, since `d` is reused, the number of times the "d clicked" message is logged does not match the number of times "D" was pressed.

Comment: I want to set a promise on A click too and want to wait for A click function to execute before executing the d click function. Can you please tell me how to do that?