# Is there a way to delay function calls or statements by a given amount in milliseconds?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a Chrome extension that, while on a Udemy course page, checks all the videos, so the certificate will become available, but I am encountering a problem where I activate the click event on all the needed buttons, but this happens so fast that my console gets spammed with net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES, and only half of all the buttons get clicked and send the POST request to the Udemy servers. Now I was looking for a sleep() function, and a google search told me there isn't one in javascript.

This is the code I am using.

```
function clickButtons() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("curriculum-item--progress--3eKMJ btn btn-default")
    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    clickButton(buttons, i)

}

}
function clickButton(buttonsArray, index){ 
    buttonsArray[index].click();
}

clickButtons();
```

If theres another way to circumvent this issue, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: use setTimeout ?

Comment: or use lodash or underscore throttle method

Comment: You can use the simple method setTimeout to delay your function by an amount in milliseconds, check https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a delay method using `aync` and `await`:

```js
const delay = t => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, t));

(async _ => { // declare as async (as we need to use await)
  console.log("Hello");
  await delay(2000); // 2000 m/s (2 second) delay
  console.log("World!");
})();
```

However, with that being said, I think it is best to maybe work out a callback of some sort which triggers another button click, which triggers the next etc...

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround/alternative. In your clickButtons() function you can wrap the call to clickButton with a setTimeout(). Like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    clickButton(buttons, i)
}, 2000);
```

Which would delay each call in your loop by your set timeout.

Also referenced here [JavaScript sleep/wait before continuing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873323/javascript-sleep-wait-before-continuing)