# Wait sometime before loading a widget onto a page

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to programming and the following code I got through an open source project.

I'm loading a widget on a website. So instead of immediately loading the widget, I want it to take 10 secs before showing the widget.

This is how I'm loading the widget.

Entire code below............

```
switch (methodName) {
            case 'init':

                const loadedObject = Object.assign(defaultConfig, item[1]);
           
                // the actual rendering of the widget
    
                const wrappingElement =
                    loadedObject.element ?? win.document.body;
                targetElement = wrappingElement.appendChild(
                    win.document.createElement('div')
                );
                targetElement.setAttribute('id', `widget-${instanceName}`);
                render(targetElement, loadedObject);

                // store indication that widget instance was initialized
                win[`loaded-${instanceName}`] = true;
                break;
    
            default:
                console.warn(`Unsupported method [${methodName}]`, item[1]);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the setTimeout function as such:

```js
switch (methodName) {
  case 'init':

    const loadedObject = Object.assign(defaultConfig, item[1]);       
    setTimeout(function(){
    
      // the actual rendering of the widget
      const wrappingElement =
          loadedObject.element ?? win.document.body;
      targetElement = wrappingElement.appendChild(
          win.document.createElement('div')
      );
      targetElement.setAttribute('id', `widget-${instanceName}`);
      render(targetElement, loadedObject);

      // store indication that widget instance was initialized
      win[`loaded-${instanceName}`] = true;

    }, 10000);

  break;
    
  default:
    console.warn(`Unsupported method [${methodName}]`, item[1]);
    }

}
```

as shown in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16873849/7485883)